# How to fix CSS errors from Teradata Covalent Templates?

Tags: css, input, scrollbar, row-height, teradata-covalent

I am using a Covalent Template for the first time for my first Angular application. I downloaded the Dashboard template from https://stackblitz.com/edit/covalent-dashboard-ynyp1w?file=main.ts and tried to customize it, when I saw this error:

[image]

1. The placeholder is mispositioned and the letters are cropped at bottom;
2. One of the DIVs is with wrong height, so an ugly scrollbar is visible at right.

I tried to look into the compiled HTML and CSS, and at the source-code, but no success on how to change what is wrong. It may be in CSS or maybe in the template property of the input-search component's decorator.

Comment: Just click the link in the question and then press F12 and press Ctrl+Shift+C and click the placeholder than you will see the compiled code at left and css at right.

Comment: As I said in the question, I was going to customize, but when I saw the errors, I tried first to fix it.

Comment: I did not do anything, just installed the template and run with ng serve. I need to fix that error before customizing the page.

Comment: I'm not seeing the exact issues you are referring to in the original template. One thing to note is that the template add some styles to the search box to make it stand out and not use the header styles.